# Give me a suggestion for UIReturnKey color/disable property

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

My application is looking like the below snap in some scenario.

[image]

There is one UITextField to get the department name from the user. Initially the "Done" button in navigation bar is set to disabled. That is, set right bar button's `enabled` property to `NO`

The UIKeyBoard of the text field was made by the below code

```
fieldForDepartment.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert; //This provides the black appearance to the keyboard
fieldForDepartment.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone; //This set the return key type as Done
fieldForDepartment.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; //This is used because i want a small cross button in the right end of my text field to clear the text field value
```

(Here `fieldForDepartment` is the UITextField instance's name)

I want to enable the "Done" button in the navigation bar if & only if, there should be atleast one letter in the text field (even may be a space). The "Done" button should get disable if there is a no letter in my text field.

For that, I implemented this code...

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([[fieldForDepartment.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] isEqual:@""] || [fieldForDepartment.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] == nil) {
        rightBarButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    else {
        rightBarButton.enabled = YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This method `textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` get called for each letter press in the keyboard.

`[fieldForDepartment.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]` will bring the current string(included the last letter pressed) from the UITextField

So when pressing a letter in the text field the application will be like this...

[image]

Here my problem comes..

The "Done" button in the UIKeyboard is always highlighted. So this violates the behavior of the "Done" button in the navigation bar. I want to disable/enable the UIKeyboard's Done button in the same way the navigation bar's Done button works. Is it possible?

Some of the questions in my mind are..

Can i disable the "Done" button of UIKeyboard?

or

Can i just change the background color & selection color of the Done button in UIKeyboard? (So that the user may feel that the button can not be pressed)

or

Can i hide the Done button in UIKeyboard?

Please suggest which one is the good way to solve my problem...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an **Auto-enable Return Key** setting in the **Text trait's** section of the Interface builder properties. It does exactly what you need, just make sure to check it.

If you need to do the change in the code, use `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` property of the UITextField (this is actually defined in the `UITextInputTraits` protocol that the class implements)

Comment: Thanks for your info.. But im not using IB in my application. I am doing all by code. Are you referring '<Text Field Name>.userInteractionEnabled' ? Thats not working :(

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the protocol `UITextInputTraits` in my .h file then i added the <textFieldName>.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically=YES; (to hide the return key) and <textFieldName>.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically=NO; (to show the return key) in the `textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method. But still it does not works..

Comment: You don't want to set it in that method, rather set it to YES somewhere in the viewDidLoad. If it's set to YES, it will automatically take care and enable / disable the return key when necessary.